# Database.open is missing, have added references, still does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I am new to C# and Visual Studio 2017 Community edition and am developing a website that shall publish data from an sql-database (sql-server-express). I have searched this site and multiple other sites to try and find an answer to my problem but none of the examples have solved my problem yet so now I am writing my own question with the hope that someone can help me.

In my cshtml-file I am trying to use this code:

```
@{var db = Database.Open("Abstracts");}
```

When writing the code in the .cshtml-file I get a red line underneath Database and when hovering over it the message

> "The name Database does not exist in the current context".

I have referenced System.Data.SqlClient but it still does not work.

PS! I have established a connection with the server and the database and can work on the database through queries in Visual Studio. Have also used SQL Server Management Studio so I know SQL Express is installed and working.

I have been struggling with this for quite a while now and am very hopeful that someone who have had the same problem also have a solution to it.

Comment: What app is it and what version of .net you are using? Can we see the connectionstring?

Comment: I believe it is version 4.0, however when I checked it looks like I have several versions installed.. The connection string looks like this: `<add name="READB" connectionString="Data Source=RBGSACER\SQLEXPRESS01;Integrated security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS01\MSSQL\DATA\emAbstracts.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SQlClient"/>`

Comment: Are sure that the sql server express is installed in your machine?

Comment: Yes, I have created several databases on the sql server, using SQL Server Management Studio. I can also see a working connection with the database in the server explorer window in visual studio. The problem I am facing is that the call on Database is not recognized in Visual Studio. I get a red line under Database and when I hover over it it reads: "The name Database does not exist in the current context"

Comment: After a google search I found out that maybe you are missing the namespace `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data`.

Comment: Thanks!  I downloaded and installed the namespace ´Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data´ but it still doesn´t work... Tried to restart Visual Studio just to see if that had any effect but it didn´t